# Prove that there exist infinitely $x, y \in \mathbb{N^*}$ such that $P(x) \vdots y$ and $P(y) \vdots x$

Tags: polynomials

Let $P(x)=x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \ldots +a_1x+1$ with integer coefficients
Prove that there exist infinitely $x, y \in \mathbb{N^*}$ such that $y | P(x)$ and $x|P(y)$

Sorry because I don't write what I've done

Please give me some hints

Comment: What does $P(x) \vdots y$ mean?

Comment: mean P(x) is divisible by y

Comment: Ah. Where I come from, that's usually written $y \mid P(x)$, $y$ divides $P(x)$.

Comment: And we use both :)

Comment: At the cost of having to explain the less common notation sometimes ;)

Comment: ok,I've just edited